# change order of object in row of listview programmaticaly

Tags: java, android

currently i have:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15:22:33 \nApr 13 1999"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" 

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/incoming_message_buble"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Hello bubbles!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
```

and it work fine.

here is adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sms_row_layout, parent, false);
    }

    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    OneComment coment = getItem(position);

    countryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);

    countryName.setText(coment.comment);


    countryName.setBackgroundResource(coment.left ? R.drawable.incoming_message_buble : R.drawable.outgoing_message_buble);
    wrapper.setGravity(coment.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

    return row;
}
```

i have to change order, for gravity left, i need shown textview comment first, and textView1 second
for gravity right, keep xml setting.

please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using multiple layouts rather than constantly reorganizing each row's layout. Override these two methods:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).left ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

And modify your `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(getItemViewType == 0) {
        // Use the left layout
    } else {
        // Use the right layout
    }
}
```